# Making sure a number is multiple of 8 via xml schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a  tag in one of the xml files and for that the XSD file contains the following line

```
<xs:element name="startBit" type="xs:integer"/>
```

Right now, I am parsing the data in the startBit field and then checking whether it is a multiple of 8 or not by checking  if the number mod 8 equals 0.

I was wondering whether I could put a rule/restriction in the xml schema itself to make sure that the number is a multiple of 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this with XML Schema, unless you can restrict the range of the numbers. For instance, you could enumerate the numbers from 0 to 255 which are a multiple of 8, but there's clearly no way to do that for the numbers from 0 to 2^32-1.

Comment: ok so I guess for a more robust solution its just better to extract the value while parsing and make sure it is a multiple of 8.

Comment: Yes, that's what I would do. XML Schema can't do everything.

Comment: alright Thanks John, I was just trying to be cheeky and try to avoid a simple if-else check in code :P